# R ifelse multiple conditions

Tags: r

My data is like

| username | compound score | age | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.5 | 26 | 2020-08-10 |
| A | 0.6 | 26 | 2020-09-01 |
| B | 0.3 | 27 | 2020-11-15 |

```
structure(list(age = c(24L, 28L, 25L, 27L, 30L, 25L, 47L, 23L, 
26L, 23L), compound = c(-0.765, 0.743, 0.1901, 0, 0, 0.743, 0.2732, 
-0.2263, 0.3612, -0.2263), Date = structure(c(18551, 18544, 18544, 
18541, 18540, 18538, 18536, 18536, 18534, 18533), class = "Date")), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 12L), class = "data.frame")
```

The code I have turns the data into long format with two conditions.

```
> twitter_wide = twitter_d %>% mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
+   group_by(username,age,Trial = ifelse(day(Date) >= 3 & month(Date) >11, 2, 1)) %>%
+   summarise(compound = mean(compound), .groups = 'drop')
```

How can I change the data to three conditions **AND A WIDE FORMAT**:

Condition1: Mean Score(compound) Date From 8.16-11.2 (T1)

Condition2: Mean Score(compound) Date From 11.3-1.20 (T2)

Condition3: Mean Score(compound) Date From 1.21-4.9  (T3)

A desired table may look like

| username | age | Mean_compound score_T1 | Mean_compound score_T2 | Mean_compound score_T3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 26 | 0.5 | 0.3 | 0.7 |
| B | 26 | 0.3 | 0.5 | 0.3 |

Comment: Please post a *reproducible* example. Show enough of your data so that we have something to work with. You can make your data available by pasting the output of `dput(twitter_wide)` into your question.

Comment: @LMc, I have around 60,000 rows, how can generate a subset of dput?

Comment: You could sample rows using the `sample` function. You could take the first n rows, using `head` like `dput(head(twitter_wide, n = 50))`.

Comment: Your `dput()` sample is missing the `username` column. Do you want it here?

Comment: @LC-datascientist, Yes!  I don't know why the dput generates 538273 usernames for me, but other variables seem ok.

Comment: I added my own fake example of the data in my solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example with fake data:

```r
# example data
twitter_d <- structure(list(username = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"), 
    `compound score` = c(0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0), 
    age = c(26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L), 
    Date = c("2020-08-16", "2020-09-01", "2020-11-14", "2021-01-20", "2020-09-12", "2020-11-02", "2020-11-15", "2021-04-09")),
        class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

# solution
library(tidyverse)

twitter_wide <- twitter_d %>% mutate(
    Condition = ifelse(Date >= "2020-08-16" & Date <= "2020-11-02", "T1", 
                    ifelse(Date >= "2020-11-03" & Date <= "2021-01-20", "T2", 
                        ifelse(Date >= "2021-01-21" & Date <= "2021-04-09", "T3", NA)))
) %>% 
    group_by(username, age, Condition) %>% 
    summarise(compound = mean(`compound score`, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = "drop") %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = Condition, names_prefix = "Mean_compound_score_", values_from = compound)
```

```r
twitter_wide
## A tibble: 2 x 5
#  username   age Mean_compound_score_T1 Mean_compound_score_T2 Mean_compound_score_T3
#  <chr>    <int>                  <dbl>                  <dbl>                  <dbl>
#1 A           26                   0.55                   0.75                     NA
#2 B           27                   0.25                   0.1                       0
```

Explanation:

I `mutate()` a new column called `Condition`. It contains `c("T1", "T2", "T3")` depending on the `Date` range that is specified for each time period. Basically, this is to group the dates.

`group_by()` and `summarise()` does the mean function that you want (that you already have).

`pivot_wider()` changes the data to wide format, using values from `compound` and grouping them by the date-grouping column `Condition`.

For more info and use for `pivot_wider()`, which is from `tidyr` package, see https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html.

Comment: Hi, It works for three conditions. Do you know why it doesn't work for four conditons

Comment: @wei How can anyone besides you know that when yu have not offered the code you tried?

Comment: @wei These conditions are coded into the `ifelse` statements. The solution shows up to three. See the pattern here and repeat it to do the fourth, fifth, sixth, etc. See its R Documentation (you can run the code `?ifelse`) for a clear description of its usage.